# Regular Expression - Replace set of String with value in oracle

Tags: regex, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

Please any one can give some idea , how to replace set of String with value in Oracle .eg :-

`String Formula: (20+OFR)/(10-OGR)`
need to Replace `OFR=100 and OGR=50` .

String Formula is dynamically changing.

Expected result  `(20+OFR)/(10-OGR)= (20+100)/(10-50)`

Comment: Shouldn't an iterated application of `replace` suffice for this kind of job ? In the vein of `replace ( <formula_as_string>, 'OFR', <variable that holds OFR> ), 'OGR', <variable that holds OGR> )` ? Do I read you wrong?

Comment: Thanks Musakkhir , may you give some idea to iterate this String .

Comment: Is this formula coming from a column?  Will the codes to substitute always be right before the closing paren? Will you then be selecting it in PL/SQL code, doing substitutions and using the formula?  Please provide more information on the environment and intended usage by editing your post using the edit link and updating the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve. But if you want to create a dynamic formula, you have to use a select statement as: select 'Your formula' from dual in order to get the result.

Here is a sample code:

```
declare
v_ofr NUMBER :=100 ;
v_ogr NUMBER := 50;
v_sql   VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN

v_sql := 'select (20+ ' || v_ofr || ')/(10-' || v_ogr ||') from dual';

execute immediate v_sql;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( v_sql);

end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Burhan , I am not expecting like this , i have to create a SP in which Formula column have (20+OFR)/(10-OGR) which can change dynamic as user choice , now where ever they put String like OFR , OGR will replaced with corresponding value .

Answer (score 0):

To answer your basic question ' how to replace set of String with value in oracle', take a look at the support for [regex in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#i1007670). For example, you could achieve your example with the following:

```
select 
      REGEXP_REPLACE( REGEXP_REPLACE('(20+OFR)/(10-OGR)',
                     'OFR',
                     '100'), 'OGR',50)
      as "names after regexp"
      from DUAL;
```

Beyond that, you'd probably have more coding, something similar to what Burhan showed above. Hope that helps.